# SVG with fixed gradient

Tags: animation, svg, transform, gradient, linear-gradients

---

### See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YrfKp/

I want to overlay a text and/or path element with a gradient but I want this gradient to be fixed - just like the css background attribute "background-attachment:fixed;" - so when I animate the text/path, the gradient shouldn't move.
I managed to achieve the desired effect animating the "x"-position but this won't work on my android tablet (4.1.2, stock browser) - see the second line in the jsfiddle. 
When animating the "transform"-attribute, the gradient will also move - see first and third line in the jsfiddle.
And while the first method works with text elements, it won't work if applied to a svg group since a group cannot have a x-coordinate. In this case I would have to animate every path element inside the group, I guess?

I just started playing around with SVGs so this might be easy for you to solve but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg class="HeadlineSVG" style="background-color:#333333;" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="350" height="250" viewBox="0 0 700 500">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#1ad1b4;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="25%" style="stop-color:#18af7c;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="45%" style="stop-color:#6effd1;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="45%" style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#6effd1;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:#25b7d2;stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#58f0fa;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="dropshadow" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB;">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0.8" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" result="flood" />
            <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" in="flood" operator="in" result="composite1" />
            <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" result="offset" />
            <feComposite in2="offset" in="SourceGraphic" operator="over" result="composite2" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <text x="0%" y="10%" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="Impact" font-size="50px" fill="url(#grad1)" text-anchor="middle" filter="url(#dropshadow)" id="Headline">
        AWESOME TEXT 1
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0" dur="15" from="875" to="-225" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>
    <text x="0%" y="20%" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="Impact" font-size="50px" fill="url(#grad1)" text-anchor="middle" filter="url(#dropshadow)" id="Headline2">
        AWESOME TEXT 2
        <animate attributeName="x" begin="0" dur="15" from="875" to="-225" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>
    <text x="0%" y="30%" dominant-baseline="central" font-family="Impact" font-size="50px" fill="url(#grad1)" text-anchor="middle" filter="url(#dropshadow)" id="Headline3">
        AWESOME TEXT 3
        <animateMotion from="875,00" to="-225,00" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>

    <g id="Vector1" fill="url(#grad1)" filter="url(#dropshadow)">
        <animateMotion from="550,-50" to="-550,-50" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <path d="M177.781,224.597l5.877,39.526h-10.504l-0.551-7.104h-3.677l-0.618,7.104h-10.626l5.243-39.526H177.781z M172.333,250.012
            c-0.52-4.477-1.042-10.011-1.565-16.602c-1.047,7.569-1.705,13.103-1.973,16.602H172.333z"/>
        <path d="M223.197,224.597l-4.577,39.526h-12.833c-1.175-6.072-2.212-12.982-3.111-20.728c-0.41,3.321-1.366,10.23-2.867,20.728
            h-12.759l-4.601-39.526h9.985l1.086,13.792l1.05,13.333c0.379-6.899,1.326-15.941,2.842-27.124h10.673
            c0.142,1.156,0.515,5.501,1.121,13.037l1.135,15.039c0.584-9.568,1.541-18.927,2.869-28.076H223.197z"/>
        <path d="M225.223,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.86v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M267.777,236.56h-9.546v-2.93c0-1.367-0.122-2.238-0.366-2.612c-0.244-0.374-0.651-0.562-1.221-0.562
            c-0.619,0-1.086,0.252-1.404,0.758c-0.317,0.505-0.476,1.27-0.476,2.296c0,1.319,0.178,2.313,0.535,2.98
            c0.341,0.668,1.309,1.474,2.905,2.417c4.575,2.716,7.457,4.944,8.645,6.686c1.188,1.742,1.782,4.549,1.782,8.423
            c0,2.816-0.33,4.891-0.989,6.226s-1.933,2.454-3.821,3.356c-1.888,0.904-4.085,1.355-6.592,1.355c-2.751,0-5.099-0.521-7.043-1.563
            c-1.945-1.041-3.219-2.368-3.821-3.979c-0.603-1.611-0.903-3.897-0.903-6.86v-2.588h9.546v4.81c0,1.481,0.134,2.434,0.403,2.856
            c0.269,0.424,0.745,0.635,1.428,0.635s1.192-0.269,1.526-0.806c0.333-0.537,0.5-1.335,0.5-2.393c0-2.327-0.317-3.849-0.952-4.565
            c-0.651-0.716-2.254-1.912-4.81-3.589c-2.556-1.692-4.248-2.921-5.078-3.687c-0.83-0.765-1.518-1.823-2.063-3.174
            c-0.545-1.351-0.818-3.076-0.818-5.176c0-3.027,0.386-5.241,1.16-6.641c0.773-1.399,2.022-2.494,3.748-3.284
            c1.725-0.789,3.809-1.184,6.25-1.184c2.669,0,4.944,0.432,6.824,1.294c1.88,0.863,3.125,1.949,3.735,3.259
            c0.61,1.311,0.916,3.536,0.916,6.677V236.56z"/>
        <path d="M295.34,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.281,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529
            c-0.985,1.367-2.315,2.417-3.992,3.149c-1.677,0.732-3.63,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.116,0-4.016-0.346-5.701-1.037
            s-3.04-1.729-4.065-3.113c-1.025-1.383-1.636-2.889-1.831-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763c0-3.971,0.093-6.783,0.281-8.435
            c0.187-1.652,0.773-3.162,1.758-4.529c0.984-1.367,2.315-2.417,3.992-3.149c1.676-0.732,3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099
            c2.116,0,4.016,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.685,0.692,3.04,1.729,4.065,3.113c1.025,1.384,1.636,2.889,1.831,4.517
            c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M285.062,234.753c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528
            c-0.204-0.513-0.623-0.769-1.257-0.769c-0.537,0-0.948,0.208-1.233,0.623c-0.285,0.415-0.427,1.64-0.427,3.674v18.457
            c0,2.295,0.093,3.711,0.281,4.248c0.187,0.537,0.623,0.806,1.306,0.806c0.7,0,1.147-0.309,1.343-0.928
            c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M330.887,224.597v39.526h-8.984l-0.012-26.685l-3.577,26.685h-6.372l-3.772-26.074l-0.012,26.074h-8.984v-39.526h13.3
            c0.394,2.376,0.801,5.177,1.22,8.403l1.459,10.054l2.362-18.457H330.887z"/>
        <path d="M335.013,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.861v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.823V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M389.041,224.597l-5.23,39.526h-15.613l-5.938-39.526h10.84c1.26,10.888,2.158,20.101,2.697,27.637
            c0.531-7.617,1.094-14.379,1.691-20.287l0.713-7.35H389.041z"/>
        <path d="M390.775,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.861v7.495h6.422v7.52h-6.422v8.691h7.545v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M435.551,241.809h-10.279v-6.87c0-1.997-0.109-3.244-0.328-3.739c-0.221-0.495-0.705-0.743-1.453-0.743
            c-0.848,0-1.385,0.301-1.611,0.903c-0.229,0.603-0.342,1.904-0.342,3.906v18.359c0,1.921,0.113,3.174,0.342,3.76
            c0.227,0.586,0.74,0.879,1.537,0.879c0.766,0,1.266-0.293,1.502-0.881s0.354-1.966,0.354-4.137v-4.968h10.279v1.541
            c0,4.091-0.289,6.993-0.867,8.704c-0.578,1.712-1.855,3.212-3.832,4.499c-1.979,1.287-4.416,1.932-7.313,1.932
            c-3.012,0-5.494-0.545-7.447-1.636s-3.246-2.601-3.881-4.528c-0.635-1.93-0.953-4.83-0.953-8.704v-11.548
            c0-2.848,0.098-4.984,0.293-6.409c0.195-1.424,0.777-2.795,1.746-4.114s2.311-2.356,4.029-3.113
            c1.717-0.757,3.689-1.135,5.92-1.135c3.027,0,5.525,0.585,7.494,1.755s3.264,2.629,3.883,4.377
            c0.617,1.747,0.928,4.465,0.928,8.155V241.809z"/>
        <path d="M459.939,224.597v7.91h-6.104v31.616h-10.277v-31.616h-6.08v-7.91H459.939z"/>
        <path d="M485.77,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.279,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529
            c-0.986,1.367-2.316,2.417-3.992,3.149c-1.678,0.732-3.631,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.117,0-4.016-0.346-5.701-1.037
            c-1.684-0.691-3.039-1.729-4.064-3.113c-1.025-1.383-1.637-2.889-1.832-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763
            c0-3.971,0.094-6.783,0.281-8.435c0.188-1.652,0.773-3.162,1.758-4.529s2.314-2.417,3.992-3.149
            c1.676-0.732,3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099c2.115,0,4.016,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.684,0.692,3.039,1.729,4.064,3.113
            c1.025,1.384,1.635,2.889,1.83,4.517c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M475.492,234.753
            c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528c-0.205-0.513-0.623-0.769-1.258-0.769c-0.537,0-0.949,0.208-1.232,0.623
            c-0.285,0.415-0.428,1.64-0.428,3.674v18.457c0,2.295,0.094,3.711,0.281,4.248c0.186,0.537,0.621,0.806,1.305,0.806
            c0.699,0,1.148-0.309,1.344-0.928c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M489.604,224.597h7.275c4.85,0,8.133,0.188,9.852,0.562c1.717,0.375,3.115,1.331,4.199,2.869
            c1.082,1.538,1.623,3.992,1.623,7.361c0,3.076-0.383,5.144-1.148,6.201c-0.766,1.058-2.27,1.693-4.516,1.904
            c2.033,0.505,3.4,1.18,4.102,2.026c0.699,0.847,1.135,1.624,1.307,2.332c0.17,0.708,0.256,2.657,0.256,5.847v10.425h-9.547v-13.135
            c0-2.116-0.166-3.426-0.5-3.931c-0.334-0.504-1.209-0.757-2.625-0.757v17.822h-10.277V224.597z M499.881,231.359v8.789
            c1.156,0,1.967-0.159,2.43-0.476c0.465-0.317,0.695-1.347,0.695-3.088v-2.173c0-1.253-0.223-2.075-0.67-2.466
            C501.887,231.555,501.068,231.359,499.881,231.359z"/>
        <path d="M540.262,224.597v39.526h-9.863v-21.191c0-3.06-0.072-4.899-0.219-5.518c-0.146-0.618-0.549-1.086-1.209-1.404
            c-0.658-0.317-2.129-0.476-4.406-0.476h-0.977v-4.608c4.768-1.026,8.389-3.136,10.863-6.33H540.262z"/>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(20,2.5)" id="Vector1" fill="url(#grad1)" filter="url(#dropshadow)">
        <animate attributeName="x" begin="0" dur="15" from="875" to="-300" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <path d="M174.753,224.597l5.877,39.526h-10.504l-0.551-7.104h-3.677l-0.618,7.104h-10.626l5.243-39.526H174.753z M169.306,250.012
            c-0.52-4.477-1.042-10.011-1.565-16.602c-1.047,7.569-1.705,13.103-1.973,16.602H169.306z"/>
        <path d="M220.169,224.597l-4.577,39.526H202.76c-1.175-6.072-2.212-12.982-3.111-20.728c-0.41,3.321-1.366,10.23-2.867,20.728
            h-12.759l-4.601-39.526h9.985l1.086,13.792l1.05,13.333c0.379-6.899,1.326-15.941,2.842-27.124h10.673
            c0.142,1.156,0.515,5.501,1.121,13.037l1.135,15.039c0.584-9.568,1.541-18.927,2.869-28.076H220.169z"/>
        <path d="M222.196,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.86v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M264.75,236.56h-9.546v-2.93c0-1.367-0.122-2.238-0.366-2.612c-0.244-0.374-0.651-0.562-1.221-0.562
            c-0.619,0-1.086,0.252-1.404,0.758c-0.317,0.505-0.476,1.27-0.476,2.296c0,1.319,0.178,2.313,0.535,2.98
            c0.341,0.668,1.309,1.474,2.905,2.417c4.575,2.716,7.457,4.944,8.645,6.686c1.188,1.742,1.782,4.549,1.782,8.423
            c0,2.816-0.33,4.891-0.989,6.226s-1.933,2.454-3.821,3.356c-1.888,0.904-4.085,1.355-6.592,1.355c-2.751,0-5.099-0.521-7.043-1.563
            c-1.945-1.041-3.219-2.368-3.821-3.979c-0.603-1.611-0.903-3.897-0.903-6.86v-2.588h9.546v4.81c0,1.481,0.134,2.434,0.403,2.856
            c0.269,0.424,0.745,0.635,1.428,0.635s1.192-0.269,1.526-0.806c0.333-0.537,0.5-1.335,0.5-2.393c0-2.327-0.317-3.849-0.952-4.565
            c-0.651-0.716-2.254-1.912-4.81-3.589c-2.556-1.692-4.248-2.921-5.078-3.687c-0.83-0.765-1.518-1.823-2.063-3.174
            c-0.545-1.351-0.818-3.076-0.818-5.176c0-3.027,0.386-5.241,1.16-6.641c0.773-1.399,2.022-2.494,3.748-3.284
            c1.725-0.789,3.809-1.184,6.25-1.184c2.669,0,4.944,0.432,6.824,1.294c1.88,0.863,3.125,1.949,3.735,3.259
            c0.61,1.311,0.916,3.536,0.916,6.677V236.56z"/>
        <path d="M292.313,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.281,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529
            c-0.985,1.367-2.315,2.417-3.992,3.149c-1.677,0.732-3.63,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.116,0-4.016-0.346-5.701-1.037
            s-3.04-1.729-4.065-3.113c-1.025-1.383-1.636-2.889-1.831-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763c0-3.971,0.093-6.783,0.281-8.435
            c0.187-1.652,0.773-3.162,1.758-4.529c0.984-1.367,2.315-2.417,3.992-3.149c1.676-0.732,3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099
            c2.116,0,4.016,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.685,0.692,3.04,1.729,4.065,3.113c1.025,1.384,1.636,2.889,1.831,4.517
            c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M282.035,234.753c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528
            c-0.204-0.513-0.623-0.769-1.257-0.769c-0.537,0-0.948,0.208-1.233,0.623c-0.285,0.415-0.427,1.64-0.427,3.674v18.457
            c0,2.295,0.093,3.711,0.281,4.248c0.187,0.537,0.623,0.806,1.306,0.806c0.7,0,1.147-0.309,1.343-0.928
            c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M327.86,224.597v39.526h-8.984l-0.012-26.685l-3.577,26.685h-6.372l-3.772-26.074l-0.012,26.074h-8.984v-39.526h13.3
            c0.394,2.376,0.801,5.177,1.22,8.403l1.459,10.054l2.362-18.457H327.86z"/>
        <path d="M331.986,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.86v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M386.014,224.597l-5.23,39.526H365.17l-5.938-39.526h10.84c1.26,10.888,2.158,20.101,2.697,27.637
            c0.531-7.617,1.094-14.379,1.691-20.287l0.713-7.35H386.014z"/>
        <path d="M387.748,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.861v7.495h6.422v7.52h-6.422v8.691h7.545v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M432.523,241.809h-10.279v-6.87c0-1.997-0.109-3.244-0.328-3.739c-0.221-0.495-0.705-0.743-1.453-0.743
            c-0.848,0-1.385,0.301-1.611,0.903c-0.229,0.603-0.342,1.904-0.342,3.906v18.359c0,1.921,0.113,3.174,0.342,3.76
            c0.227,0.586,0.74,0.879,1.537,0.879c0.766,0,1.266-0.293,1.502-0.881s0.354-1.966,0.354-4.137v-4.968h10.279v1.541
            c0,4.091-0.289,6.993-0.867,8.704c-0.578,1.712-1.855,3.212-3.832,4.499c-1.979,1.287-4.416,1.932-7.313,1.932
            c-3.012,0-5.494-0.545-7.447-1.636s-3.246-2.601-3.881-4.528c-0.635-1.93-0.953-4.83-0.953-8.704v-11.548
            c0-2.848,0.098-4.984,0.293-6.409c0.195-1.424,0.777-2.795,1.746-4.114s2.311-2.356,4.029-3.113
            c1.717-0.757,3.689-1.135,5.92-1.135c3.027,0,5.525,0.585,7.494,1.755s3.264,2.629,3.883,4.377
            c0.617,1.747,0.928,4.465,0.928,8.155V241.809z"/>
        <path d="M456.912,224.597v7.91h-6.104v31.616h-10.277v-31.616h-6.08v-7.91H456.912z"/>
        <path d="M482.742,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.279,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529
            c-0.986,1.367-2.316,2.417-3.992,3.149c-1.678,0.732-3.631,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.117,0-4.016-0.346-5.701-1.037
            c-1.684-0.691-3.039-1.729-4.064-3.113c-1.025-1.383-1.637-2.889-1.832-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763
            c0-3.971,0.094-6.783,0.281-8.435c0.188-1.652,0.773-3.162,1.758-4.529s2.314-2.417,3.992-3.149
            c1.676-0.732,3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099c2.115,0,4.016,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.684,0.692,3.039,1.729,4.064,3.113
            c1.025,1.384,1.635,2.889,1.83,4.517c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M472.465,234.753
            c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528c-0.205-0.513-0.623-0.769-1.258-0.769c-0.537,0-0.949,0.208-1.232,0.623
            c-0.285,0.415-0.428,1.64-0.428,3.674v18.457c0,2.295,0.094,3.711,0.281,4.248c0.186,0.537,0.621,0.806,1.305,0.806
            c0.699,0,1.148-0.309,1.344-0.928c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M486.576,224.597h7.275c4.85,0,8.133,0.188,9.852,0.562c1.717,0.375,3.115,1.331,4.199,2.869
            c1.082,1.538,1.623,3.992,1.623,7.361c0,3.076-0.383,5.144-1.148,6.201c-0.766,1.058-2.27,1.693-4.516,1.904
            c2.033,0.505,3.4,1.18,4.102,2.026c0.699,0.847,1.135,1.624,1.307,2.332c0.17,0.708,0.256,2.657,0.256,5.847v10.425h-9.547v-13.135
            c0-2.116-0.166-3.426-0.5-3.931c-0.334-0.504-1.209-0.757-2.625-0.757v17.822h-10.277V224.597z M496.854,231.359v8.789
            c1.156,0,1.967-0.159,2.43-0.476c0.465-0.317,0.695-1.347,0.695-3.088v-2.173c0-1.253-0.223-2.075-0.67-2.466
            C498.859,231.555,498.041,231.359,496.854,231.359z"/>
        <path d="M543.289,257.385v6.738h-21.703l0.006-5.64c6.428-10.514,10.25-17.021,11.463-19.519c1.211-2.498,1.818-4.447,1.818-5.847
            c0-1.074-0.184-1.875-0.551-2.405c-0.367-0.529-0.924-0.793-1.674-0.793s-1.309,0.293-1.676,0.879
            c-0.365,0.586-0.549,1.75-0.549,3.491v3.76h-8.838v-1.44c0-2.213,0.113-3.959,0.342-5.237c0.227-1.277,0.789-2.535,1.684-3.772
            c0.895-1.237,2.059-2.173,3.492-2.808c1.432-0.635,3.148-0.952,5.15-0.952c3.922,0,6.889,0.973,8.9,2.917
            c2.01,1.945,3.014,4.407,3.014,7.385c0,2.263-0.564,4.655-1.697,7.178c-1.131,2.523-4.463,7.878-9.998,16.064H543.289z"/>
    </g>

    <g id="Vector3" fill="url(#grad1)" filter="url(#dropshadow)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0" dur="15" from="550,50" to="-550,50" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <path d="M174.045,224.597l5.877,39.526h-10.504l-0.551-7.104h-3.677l-0.618,7.104h-10.626l5.243-39.526H174.045z M168.598,250.012
            c-0.52-4.477-1.042-10.011-1.565-16.602c-1.047,7.569-1.705,13.103-1.973,16.602H168.598z"/>
        <path d="M219.461,224.597l-4.577,39.526h-12.833c-1.175-6.072-2.212-12.982-3.111-20.728c-0.41,3.321-1.366,10.23-2.867,20.728
            h-12.759l-4.601-39.526h9.985l1.086,13.792l1.05,13.333c0.379-6.899,1.326-15.941,2.842-27.124h10.673
            c0.142,1.156,0.515,5.501,1.121,13.037l1.135,15.039c0.584-9.568,1.541-18.927,2.869-28.076H219.461z"/>
        <path d="M221.488,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.86v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M264.042,236.56h-9.546v-2.93c0-1.367-0.122-2.238-0.366-2.612c-0.244-0.374-0.651-0.562-1.221-0.562
            c-0.619,0-1.086,0.252-1.404,0.758c-0.317,0.505-0.476,1.27-0.476,2.296c0,1.319,0.178,2.313,0.535,2.98
            c0.341,0.668,1.309,1.474,2.905,2.417c4.575,2.716,7.457,4.944,8.645,6.686c1.188,1.742,1.782,4.549,1.782,8.423
            c0,2.816-0.33,4.891-0.989,6.226s-1.933,2.454-3.821,3.356c-1.888,0.904-4.085,1.355-6.592,1.355c-2.751,0-5.099-0.521-7.043-1.563
            c-1.945-1.041-3.219-2.368-3.821-3.979c-0.603-1.611-0.903-3.897-0.903-6.86v-2.588h9.546v4.81c0,1.481,0.134,2.434,0.403,2.856
            c0.269,0.424,0.745,0.635,1.428,0.635s1.192-0.269,1.526-0.806c0.333-0.537,0.5-1.335,0.5-2.393c0-2.327-0.317-3.849-0.952-4.565
            c-0.651-0.716-2.254-1.912-4.81-3.589c-2.556-1.692-4.248-2.921-5.078-3.687c-0.83-0.765-1.518-1.823-2.063-3.174
            c-0.545-1.351-0.818-3.076-0.818-5.176c0-3.027,0.386-5.241,1.16-6.641c0.773-1.399,2.022-2.494,3.748-3.284
            c1.725-0.789,3.809-1.184,6.25-1.184c2.669,0,4.944,0.432,6.824,1.294c1.88,0.863,3.125,1.949,3.735,3.259
            c0.61,1.311,0.916,3.536,0.916,6.677V236.56z"/>
        <path d="M291.605,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.281,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529
            c-0.985,1.367-2.315,2.417-3.992,3.149c-1.677,0.732-3.63,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.116,0-4.016-0.346-5.701-1.037
            s-3.04-1.729-4.065-3.113c-1.025-1.383-1.636-2.889-1.831-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763c0-3.971,0.093-6.783,0.281-8.435
            c0.187-1.652,0.773-3.162,1.758-4.529c0.984-1.367,2.315-2.417,3.992-3.149c1.676-0.732,3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099
            c2.116,0,4.016,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.685,0.692,3.04,1.729,4.065,3.113c1.025,1.384,1.636,2.889,1.831,4.517
            c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M281.327,234.753c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528
            c-0.204-0.513-0.623-0.769-1.257-0.769c-0.537,0-0.948,0.208-1.233,0.623c-0.285,0.415-0.427,1.64-0.427,3.674v18.457
            c0,2.295,0.093,3.711,0.281,4.248c0.187,0.537,0.623,0.806,1.306,0.806c0.7,0,1.147-0.309,1.343-0.928
            c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M327.152,224.597v39.526h-8.984l-0.012-26.685l-3.577,26.685h-6.372l-3.772-26.074l-0.012,26.074h-8.984v-39.526h13.3
            c0.394,2.376,0.801,5.177,1.22,8.403l1.459,10.054l2.362-18.457H327.152z"/>
        <path d="M331.278,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.86v7.495h6.421v7.52h-6.421v8.691h7.544v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M385.307,224.597l-5.23,39.526h-15.613l-5.939-39.526h10.84c1.26,10.888,2.16,20.101,2.698,27.637
            c0.53-7.617,1.095-14.379,1.69-20.287l0.715-7.35H385.307z"/>
        <path d="M387.039,224.597h17.139v7.91h-6.859v7.495h6.42v7.52h-6.42v8.691h7.543v7.91h-17.822V224.597z"/>
        <path d="M431.814,241.809h-10.277v-6.87c0-1.997-0.109-3.244-0.33-3.739c-0.219-0.495-0.705-0.743-1.453-0.743
            c-0.846,0-1.383,0.301-1.611,0.903c-0.229,0.603-0.342,1.904-0.342,3.906v18.359c0,1.921,0.113,3.174,0.342,3.76
            s0.74,0.879,1.539,0.879c0.764,0,1.266-0.293,1.502-0.881c0.234-0.588,0.354-1.966,0.354-4.137v-4.968h10.277v1.541
            c0,4.091-0.289,6.993-0.865,8.704c-0.578,1.712-1.855,3.212-3.834,4.499c-1.977,1.287-4.416,1.932-7.313,1.932
            c-3.012,0-5.492-0.545-7.445-1.636s-3.248-2.601-3.883-4.528c-0.635-1.93-0.951-4.83-0.951-8.704v-11.548
            c0-2.848,0.098-4.984,0.293-6.409c0.195-1.424,0.777-2.795,1.746-4.114c0.967-1.318,2.311-2.356,4.027-3.113
            s3.689-1.135,5.92-1.135c3.027,0,5.525,0.585,7.496,1.755c1.969,1.17,3.262,2.629,3.881,4.377c0.619,1.747,0.928,4.465,0.928,8.155
            V241.809z"/>
        <path d="M456.205,224.597v7.91h-6.104v31.616h-10.279v-31.616h-6.078v-7.91H456.205z"/>
        <path d="M482.035,247.741c0,3.972-0.094,6.783-0.281,8.435c-0.188,1.652-0.773,3.162-1.758,4.529s-2.316,2.417-3.992,3.149
            s-3.629,1.099-5.859,1.099c-2.115,0-4.016-0.346-5.699-1.037c-1.686-0.691-3.041-1.729-4.066-3.113
            c-1.025-1.383-1.635-2.889-1.83-4.517s-0.293-4.476-0.293-8.545v-6.763c0-3.971,0.094-6.783,0.281-8.435
            c0.186-1.652,0.771-3.162,1.758-4.529c0.984-1.367,2.314-2.417,3.99-3.149s3.629-1.099,5.859-1.099
            c2.115,0,4.018,0.346,5.701,1.038c1.686,0.692,3.039,1.729,4.064,3.113c1.025,1.384,1.637,2.889,1.832,4.517
            c0.195,1.628,0.293,4.476,0.293,8.545V247.741z M471.756,234.753c0-1.839-0.102-3.015-0.305-3.528s-0.623-0.769-1.258-0.769
            c-0.537,0-0.947,0.208-1.232,0.623s-0.428,1.64-0.428,3.674v18.457c0,2.295,0.094,3.711,0.281,4.248s0.623,0.806,1.307,0.806
            c0.699,0,1.146-0.309,1.342-0.928c0.195-0.618,0.293-2.092,0.293-4.419V234.753z"/>
        <path d="M485.867,224.597h7.275c4.85,0,8.135,0.188,9.852,0.562c1.717,0.375,3.117,1.331,4.199,2.869s1.623,3.992,1.623,7.361
            c0,3.076-0.383,5.144-1.146,6.201c-0.766,1.058-2.271,1.693-4.518,1.904c2.035,0.505,3.402,1.18,4.102,2.026
            c0.699,0.847,1.137,1.624,1.307,2.332c0.172,0.708,0.256,2.657,0.256,5.847v10.425h-9.545v-13.135c0-2.116-0.168-3.426-0.5-3.931
            c-0.334-0.504-1.209-0.757-2.625-0.757v17.822h-10.279V224.597z M496.146,231.359v8.789c1.154,0,1.965-0.159,2.43-0.476
            c0.463-0.317,0.695-1.347,0.695-3.088v-2.173c0-1.253-0.225-2.075-0.672-2.466S497.334,231.359,496.146,231.359z"/>
        <path d="M539.848,241.723c1.496,0.505,2.611,1.332,3.344,2.479c0.732,1.148,1.1,3.839,1.1,8.073c0,3.143-0.359,5.582-1.074,7.316
            c-0.717,1.734-1.953,3.053-3.711,3.957c-1.758,0.903-4.014,1.355-6.764,1.355c-3.125,0-5.578-0.525-7.359-1.574
            c-1.783-1.051-2.955-2.336-3.516-3.857c-0.563-1.521-0.844-4.163-0.844-7.923v-3.125h9.863v6.421c0,1.709,0.102,2.795,0.307,3.26
            c0.203,0.463,0.654,0.695,1.354,0.695c0.766,0,1.27-0.293,1.514-0.879s0.367-2.115,0.367-4.59v-2.734
            c0-1.514-0.172-2.62-0.514-3.32c-0.342-0.7-0.846-1.16-1.514-1.379s-1.961-0.346-3.881-0.378v-5.737
            c2.344,0,3.791-0.089,4.346-0.269c0.553-0.179,0.951-0.569,1.195-1.172c0.244-0.602,0.367-1.546,0.367-2.832v-2.197
            c0-1.383-0.143-2.295-0.428-2.734s-0.729-0.659-1.33-0.659c-0.684,0-1.152,0.232-1.404,0.696s-0.379,1.453-0.379,2.966v3.247
            h-9.863v-3.369c0-3.776,0.863-6.327,2.588-7.654c1.725-1.326,4.469-1.99,8.229-1.99c4.703,0,7.893,0.919,9.57,2.757
            c1.676,1.838,2.514,4.392,2.514,7.661c0,2.212-0.301,3.81-0.902,4.794C542.418,240.012,541.361,240.91,539.848,241.723z"/>
    </g>
```

### See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YrfKp/

The first method I tried was overlaying the text element with a pattern image defined in  but this causes Chrome to slow down to an unacceptable framerate. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gU6nK/

The next step would be to remove all animate-tags inside the svg and let snapsvg handle the animations.
Keeping the text elements would be nice so I can change the text with javascript but I think using paths achieves a better performance? Also I wouldn't have to include a custom webfont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a `<rect>` element that fills the whole space and then setting the gradient on that. Then create a clipPath with the text elements in and that will clip the rect to the text outlines so only the parts of the rect that intersect the gradient will show through.

Since the rect won't move neither will the gradient. The text in the clipPath is what moves.

There's [an example in the SVG testsuite](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/masking-path-04-b.html) that shows a text clipPath (it's clipping an image rather than a rect with a gradient but I'm sure you can adjust it to fit).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried that (see http://jsfiddle.net/VW39e/) and while this works in firefox and also smoothly in chrome, the animation isn't displayed in either internet explorer 9/10 nor the android stock browser.
While the android browser could be left out, IE9 and up should be supported.
And with this method I cannot achieve the drop shadow effect or do I?

Comment: IE doesn't support SMIL animation so your original examples don't work there either. You'd have to do the animation in javascript to support IE or maybe try fakeSMIL. You could achieve the drop shadow different rects, one offset and blurred to be the shadow.

Comment: Whooops, you're right. Sorry, my fault. I'll try to improve the latest version in a few hours when I'm in the mood and I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: If you have other questions, I'd ask them separately rather than updating this one.

Comment: I created a version using clipped rectangles. http://jsfiddle.net/VXhk4/
Looks good in Firefox and Chrome but the clipPath won't work in IE9/10/11. Any Ideas?

Comment: Ask another question about it.